# How to add dummy record to the existing column in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a data frame where I want to add one dummy record each. So, to do that, I read a dataframe from a parquet file, and created a list out of them., and then used python dict(zip()) to add them. Below is the code snippet.

```
prem_df = read_parquet_file(folder_path, logger)
row_list = prem_df.select(col("cat")).collect()
y = [o[0] for o in row_list]          
t = y.append("ABC")


row_list1 = prem_df.select(col("Val")).collect()
x = [o[0] for o in row_list1]          
p = x.append("23.54")

dict(zip(t, p))
```

But not sure how would I create a dataframe out of it again, as I need to merge it back to the DF `prem_df`.

Basically, I want to add ABC at the end of the `"cat"` column, and `"23.54"` at the end of the `"Val"` column in such a way that if I filter on `"cat" == "ABC`, I should get the `"Val"` as `23.54`.

```
df.filter("cat" == "ABC).select(col("cat", "val")
```

Note: the parquet file has 43 columns in total.
Please suggest.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concat.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['cat1', 1]], ['cat', 'Val'])
df.show(truncate=False)

df.withColumn('cat', f.concat(f.col('cat'), f.lit('ABC'))) \
  .withColumn('Val', f.concat(f.col('Val'), f.lit(23.54))) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+----+---+
|cat |Val|
+----+---+
|cat1|1  |
+----+---+

+-------+------+
|cat    |Val   |
+-------+------+
|cat1ABC|123.54|
+-------+------+
```

Comment: Ok, will try and let know

Comment: Its not working, as the "cat" column has cat1ABC. Hence, if I execute the below query, I am getting empty output.
prem_df.filter(col("cat") == "ABC").select(col("cat"), col("Val")).show(truncate=False)

Comment: I have used capical "Cat" column so it should be modified.